# How to reset all the route params when user click navigation.goback from header?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Before going into the `params issue` I wanna explain my situation first.

I got a `productlist` page and `productdetails` page.

When I want to navigate from `productlist` to `productdetails A` I use `navigation.navigate`.

```
navigation.navigate('CaseDetails', {
                screen: 'CaseDetails',
                params: {
                    title: info.title,
                    summary: info.summary,
                },
            })
```

When I go from `productdetails A` to `productdetails B` I use `navigation.push`

```
navigation.push('CaseDetails', {
            screen: 'CaseDetails',
            params: {
                title: item.title,
                summary: item.summary,
            },
        });
```

The thing is in my caseDetails page I got 2 set of params data.

---

When I went from `productlist` to `productdetails A`

The params are located in `route.params`

---

When I went from `productdetails A` to `productdetails B`

The params are located in `route.params.params`

So to show the correct data I am display the data by making a condition like this

```
{route.params?.params?.title === undefined
        ? renderPageView(route.params)
        : renderPageView(route.params?.params)}
```

here is the renderPageView function

```
const renderPageView = (item) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={globalStyle.articleLandingContainer}>
          <View style={globalStyle.articleLandingOverlay}></View>
          <Text style={styles.landingText}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.landingPara}>{item.summary}</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

So the initial circle of going around is pages is fine. But in the 2nd circle of going around

When going from `productlist` to `productdetails A` The `route.params?.params?.title` still exist

So the app is showing me the data from  `productdetails B` instead of  `productdetails A`.

So in my drawerNavigator. I try resetting the params like this but Its doing nothing

```
clearParams = () => {
     navigation.setParams({
       title: undefined,
       summary: undefined,
     });
  };

<Icon.Button
         name="arrow-left"
         size={25}
         backgroundColor={headerColor}
         onPress={() => {
          navigation.goBack(), clearParams();
 }}></Icon.Button>
```

What should I do to make it works

Comment: How are you passing the params between the 2 screen?

Comment: Have you tried to first `clearParams()` and after that `.goBack()` ? :)

Comment: @NicolaeMaties Yep, not working. I think when user press go back and stay in the `list component` for a while the app got plenty of time to clear the params. Before user press the details page again

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @AnOldGuyandHisDog Hey I post an answer which fix my issue. Hope its help yours too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for other cases but this syntax fix my issue.

```
navigation.navigate('CaseDetails', {
            screen: 'CaseDetails',
                        params: {
                            title: info.title,
                            summary: info.summary,
                            params: {
                                title: undefined,
                                summary: undefined,
                            },
                        },
                    }
```

Inside the `casedetails` component when communicating between two details

```
navigation.push('CaseDetails', {
            screen: 'CaseDetails',
            params: {
                title: item.title,
                summary: item.summary,
            },
        });
```